# angular - setter not updating repeated values

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection

I have a scenario where I have a login page with a child custom mat form field component. On submission, the value of the input field is sent through an api request for validation.

I then send a boolean value to the child mat form field component, so as to display a `mat-error` and change outline color in case the input received is of value `false`.

This seemed like some simple logic. However I reached a scenario where, of course, the user can submit invalid inputs repeatedly. While the api response will always return `false`, I can only communicate the first `false` value to the child component, since the subsequent `false` values won't be considered as "changes". As you can see:

The first `false` value is detected, template changes are made correctly:

[image]

Subsequent `false` values are not detected:

[image]

Here is where the boolean value is sent, in the parent component:

```
onContinue(input: string){
    if(input){
        this.storeLoginInput = input;
        this.loginStore();
    }
}

loginStore(){
    this.authService.requestWebzineId("domain="+this.storeLoginInput).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.stat === "ok"){
            ...
            ...
            this.inputIsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            this.inputIsValid = false;
        }
    });
}
```

And the template:

```
<app-custom-input
    [matLabel]="'Name of your store'"
    [inputType]="'text'"
    [showContinueButton]="true"
    [inputIsValid]="inputIsValid"
    (inputContinue)="onContinue($event)"
></app-custom-input>
```

Finally, here is the child custom input component:

```
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit {

    ...
    @Output() inputContinue = new EventEmitter<string>();
    control: FormControl = new FormControl("");; 

    private _inputIsValid: boolean;

    @Input()
    set inputIsValid(val: boolean) {
        if(!val){
            this.control.setErrors({"invalidStore": true});
        }
        this._inputIsValid = val;
    }

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    getErrorMessage(){
        return this.control.hasError("invalidStore") ? "Not a valid store" : "";
    }

    onContinueAction() {
        this.inputContinue.emit(this.control.value);
    }
    ...
}
```

I just want to inform this child component with a boolean value everytime the input is submitted. What can I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Always you make setErrors, you need use `updateValueAndValidity`:https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity.

Comment: @Eliseo Please provide an example.